# What query can I use to retrieve a list of all tables and columns from ALL linked servers?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, linked-server

I found this query that gives me all tables and columns:

```
SELECT schema_name(tab.schema_id) as schema_name,
    tab.name as table_name, 
    col.column_id,
    col.name as column_name, 
    t.name as data_type,    
    col.max_length,
    col.precision
FROM sys.tables as tab
    INNER JOIN sys.columns as col
        on tab.object_id = col.object_id
    LEFT JOIN sys.types as t
    on col.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
ORDER BY schema_name,
    table_name, 
    column_id;
```

But it's showing me results from just 1 particular database. It's ignoring a few other linked servers that also have several of their own databases.

Is there a query that will scrape all tables from every visible server/database?

I also read about the `sys.servers` command which does give me the list of visible servers but I'm not experienced enough with queries to write a statement achieving the above.

Comment: Honestly, any such query would be messy; especially if any of those linked servers aren't using the SQL Server data engine. This smells like [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info), if I am honest. What is the problem you are *actually* trying to solve here?

Comment: @Larnu The problem is that I am not familiar with the structure and the content of the tables and the servers, and as a first step I'm trying to export the structure (servers>databases>tables>columns) it so I can use some analytics on it.

Would the query be less messy if there's a way to use the query I found above, but specify which linked server it's run for? Then I can just run 5-6 queries (one for each linked server) and still achieve what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use dynamic SQL to select from all databases. You also need to use dynamic SQL to select from all linked servers. So you need dynamic over dynamic.

```sql
CREATE TABLE #DBs (dbname nvarchar(515) NOT NULL);

INSERT #DBs (dbname)
SELECT QUOTENAME(d.name)
FROM sys.databases d;

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);

SELECT @sql =
  STRING_AGG(CAST(
    '
INSERT #DBs (dbname)
SELECT QUOTENAME(' + QUOTENAME(s.name, '''') + ') + ''.'' + QUOTENAME(d.name)
FROM ' + QUOTENAME(s.name) + '.master.sys.databases d
'   AS nvarchar(max)), '
;
'  )
FROM sys.servers s
WHERE s.server_id > 0;

PRINT @sql;

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;


SELECT @sql = STRING_AGG(CAST(
    '
SELECT
    ''' + REPLACE(d.dbname, '''', '''''')  + ''' as db_name,
    schema_name(tab.schema_id) as schema_name,
    tab.name as table_name, 
    col.column_id,
    col.name as column_name, 
    t.name as data_type,    
    col.max_length,
    col.precision
FROM ' + d.dbname + '.sys.tables as tab
    INNER JOIN ' + d.dbname + '.sys.columns as col
        on tab.object_id = col.object_id
    LEFT JOIN ' + d.dbname + '.sys.types as t
    on col.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
'  AS nvarchar(max)), '
UNION ALL
'  )
  + '
  ORDER BY
    db_name,
    schema_name,
    table_name, 
    column_id;
  '
FROM #DBs d;

PRINT @sql;

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;

DROP TABLE #DBs;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/tLTV1t__)